# I want to know the code between the comments

Tags: python

The function get_avergae_score() is a function that returns the number of subjects entered and the average test score after inputting the test scores for a subject using a variable factor *. I wonder if I should put the code

```py
def get_avergae_score(*scores):

    ### Modify code here ###  

    ### End of your code ###

    return cnt, average

n, avg = get_avergae_score(95, 100, 90)
print(n, "Average score for the subject:", avg, "\n")

n, avg = get_avergae_score(90, 90, 80, 90)
print(n, "Average score for the subject:", avg, "\n")
```

```
3. Subject average score: 95.0

4. Subject average score: 87.5
```

I'm just curious about what to put between comments I know it's a question to ask

Comment: Good old formula to calculate average: Add them up, then divide. Obligatory link: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: I'm just curious about why you put the tag `reactjs`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the length of the input tuple and the sum of its contents. You also need to account for the possibility that the tuple has zero length.

```
def get_average_score(*scores):
    if (_len := len(scores)) > 0:
        return _len, sum(scores) / _len
    # implicitly return None if the input tuple has zero length
```